# How to serialize-deserialize object using HTTP GetAsync method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, .net-4.6

After I upgraded the framework of web app from 4.0 to 4.6 I found that there is no more `ReadAsAsync()` method in HTTP protocol library, instead of `ReadAsAsync()` there is `GetAsync()`. I need to serialize my custom object using `GetAsync()`.

The code using ReadAsAsync():

```
CustomResponse customResponse = client.ReadAsAsync("api/xxx", new StringContent(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(request), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

Another example based on ReadAsAsync()

```
CustomResponse customResponse = await Response.Content.ReadAsAsync<CustomResponse>();
```

How to achieve same goal using `GetAsync()` method ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use it this way:
(you might want to run it on another thread to avoid waiting for response)

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(page))
    {
        using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
        {
            string contentString = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var myParsedObject = (MyObject)(new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(contentString ,typeof(MyObject));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I need to serialize my custom object using GetAsync(). Your example use HttpResponseMessage, but I need to use CustomResponse object.

Comment: Why do you *need* to use a `CustomResponse`, exactly? This is how I create a Http request to an API and then just use my favourite de-serializer on the `contentString` - I'm pretty sure it's a "standard way" of doing it. What's different with using a`CustomResponse`?

Comment: In my app I use custom objects and I want to get the response and serialize it. I would like to have just few lines like in the provided examples.

Comment: @DmitryKazakov This is exactly what de/serializers are for - the remote app (usually a WebApp/API etc.), serializes a custom object at one end, and sends the serialized string. Then, the other (your own/local app) can de-serialize this string into the same type of custom object... This is a few lines of code. I use this exact (nearly) method day-in-day-out to get responses from Web Servers, and parse out objects. Again, I don't see how using a `CustomResponse` would benefit you differently?

Comment: I have the app built already. I had to upgrade framework version to add some functionality, but I do not want to refactor most of code (moreover it is not possible because few libraries are compiled and there is no source code). I just want to use GetAsync() in the same way like it was with ReadAsAsync() and serialization to keep the app working with compiled dlls.

Comment: Dmitry, how about replacing your serialization code to: (your Type)(new JavaScriptSerializer()).Deserialize(contentString,typeof(your Type)?

Comment: Post it as an answer with the full-code example, I will test and mark as a correct answer if it works.